# ubuntu 16.04 zero updates

Tags: 16.04, apt

For about a month now I'm getting:

```
0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

This is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-171-generic x86_64) on Amazon.

Usually I see notice of available updates, in the console. Should I be concerned?

Any advice appreciated.

Output of `apt update`:
There appears to be something wrong!

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid InRelease
  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
Err:3 http://mariadb.mirror.anstey.ca/repo/10.3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:6 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:7 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
Err:8 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:67 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-ppc64el/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http://mariadb.mirror.anstey.ca/repo/10.3/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:67 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-ppc64el/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:66 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB.list:3
```

Comment: Only 'main' repository is still supported for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the exception of the kylin desktop (ie. all flavors are now EOL), thus the number of updates have greatly reduced anyway.  Do you get normal & appropriate ouput with `sudo apt update` command?  If so, I'd next check the status of your used mirror (is it behind? esp. *unknown* because it's days-behind counter has overflowed; ie. change mirror..)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem. I had a `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Acquire {

  HTTP::proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8080";

  HTTPS::proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8080";

}
```

I changed the name to `apt_old.conf` and then was able to run apt update and apt upgrade.

I believe the issue was an un documented change back in January when I added apt.conf
to try and resolve another issue.

Moral of the story: Always document any changes made!